# iOS Swift 3 Storing Values To Realm

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

In my app I'm using realm to store and retrieve data's. Here is my API result. I need to store this values to realm database.

```
{
  "cc": [
    {
      "id": 142,
      "firm": 2,
      "specialization_id": 2,
      "specialization_name": "Alternative",
      "number": "234",
      "title": "Push test",
      "ear": "2012",
      "description": "",
      "status": "Open",
      "open_date": "2017-05-22",
      "close_date": null,
      "closing_comments": null,
      "type_id": 99,
      "type_name": "Tax Reference",
      "record_id": 57,
      "record_name": "Court of India",
      "type": "Court",
      "other_party": [],
      "billing_type": "Retainer",
      "applicants": [
        {
          "type": "Contact",
          "id": 31816,
          "name": "1.Mrs V.Dhanalakshmi &  Another",
          "email": null,
          "firm_id": 2,
          "company_id": null,
          "has_portal_access": false,
          "mobile_number": null,
          "street_address": null,
          "locality": null,
          "city": null,
          "state": null,
          "postal_code": null,
          "landmark": null
        }
      ],
    }
    ]
}
```

Problem is I can able to store Parent Values like `id,firm, specialisation_id,etc,.` But I not able to store values like `applicants` details. Here is my tried code:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm
import ObjectMapper

class CaseResponseData: Mappable
{
    var data:[CaseAreaEntity]?

    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience init?(map: Map)
    {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        data <- map["court_case"]
    }
}

//Case Details
class CaseAreaEntity:Object, Mappable
{
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var firm_id = 0
    dynamic var specialization_id = 0
    dynamic var specialization_name = ""
    dynamic var number = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var case_year = ""
    dynamic var description2 = ""
    dynamic var status = ""
    dynamic var open_date = ""
    dynamic var close_date = ""
    dynamic var closing_comments = ""
    dynamic var case_type_id = 0
    dynamic var case_type_name = ""
    dynamic var court_record_id = 0
    dynamic var court_record_name = ""
    dynamic var court_type = ""
    dynamic var client_type = ""
    dynamic var billing_type = ""
    dynamic var referred_by = ""
    var applicants = List<ApplicantsEntity>()


    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience init?(map: Map)
    {
        self.init()
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String?
    {
        return "id"
    }


    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        id <- map["id"]
        firm_id  <- map["firm_id"]
        specialization_id    <- map["specialization_id"]
        specialization_name <- map["specialization_name"]
        number <- map["number"]
        title <- map["title"]
        case_year <- map["case_year"]
        description2 <- map["description"]
        status <- map["status"]
        open_date <- map["open_date"]
        close_date <- map["close_date"]
        closing_comments <- map["closing_comments"]
        case_type_id <- map["case_type_id"]
        case_type_name <- map["case_type_name"]
        court_record_id <- map["court_record_id"]
        court_record_name <- map["court_record_name"]
        court_type <- map["court_type"]
        client_type <- map["client_type"]
        billing_type <- map["billing_type"]
        referred_by <- map["referred_by"]
        applicants <- map["applicants"]
    }
}
//Applicants Details
class ApplicantsEntity: Object,Mappable
{
    dynamic var applicant_id = 0
    dynamic var applicantable_type = ""
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var first_name = ""
    dynamic var last_name = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var firm_id = 0
    dynamic var company_id = 0
    dynamic var has_portal_access = Bool()
    dynamic var mobile_number = ""
    dynamic var phone_number = ""
    dynamic var fax = ""
    dynamic var website = ""
    dynamic var street_address = ""
    dynamic var locality = ""
    dynamic var city = ""
    dynamic var state = ""
    dynamic var postal_code = ""
    dynamic var landmark = ""

    //Impl. of Mappable protocol
    required convenience init?(map: Map)
    {
        self.init()
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String?
    {
       return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        applicant_id <- map["applicant_id"]
        applicantable_type  <- map["applicantable_type"]
        id    <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        first_name <- map["first_name"]
        last_name <- map["last_name"]
        email  <- map["email"]
        firm_id  <- map["firm_id"]
        company_id  <- map["company_id"]
        has_portal_access  <- map["has_portal_access"]
        mobile_number    <- map["mobile_number"]
        phone_number <- map["phone_number"]
        fax  <- map["fax"]
        website    <- map["website"]
        street_address <- map["street_address"]
        locality  <- map["locality"]
        city    <- map["city"]
        state <- map["state"]
        postal_code  <- map["postal_code"]
        landmark    <- map["landmark"]
    }
}
```

When Retriving values `applicant` values are not appearing because those values are not stored. Here is my tried code for creating realm:

```
let JSON = response.result.value
let realm:Realm = try! Realm()
let resData = Mapper<CaseResponseData>().map(JSONObject: JSON)                   
try! realm.write
{
  realm.delete(realm.objects(CaseAreaEntity.self))
  realm.add((resData?.data!)!, update: true)
  //realm.create(CaseAreaEntity.self, value: (resData?.data!)!, update: true)
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing or the issue you're having. It would help if you elaborated on what the exact issue is.

Comment: @Aaron I'm not getting any error there but applicants values are not stored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing these 2 things, change the type of your `applicants` property:

```
let applicants = List<ApplicantsEntity>()
```

and add primaryKeys to both classes:

```
class ApplicantsEntity: Object
{
    dynamic var "id" = ""
    ...
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

With this you should be able to use this line that works like a charm:

```
realm.create(CaseAreaEntity.self, value: json, update: true)
```

Have a look at [this part][1] of Realm's documentation for more details.

EDIT:
You don't neead the `ObjectMapper`. Try modifying your `Object` subclasses like this:

```
import RealmSwift

class CaseAreaEntity: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var firm_id = 0
    dynamic var specialization_id = 0
    dynamic var specialization_name = ""
    dynamic var number = ""
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var case_year = ""
    dynamic var description2 = ""
    dynamic var status = ""
    dynamic var open_date = ""
    dynamic var close_date = ""
    dynamic var closing_comments = ""
    dynamic var case_type_id = 0
    dynamic var case_type_name = ""
    dynamic var court_record_id = 0
    dynamic var court_record_name = ""
    dynamic var court_type = ""
    dynamic var client_type = ""
    dynamic var billing_type = ""
    dynamic var referred_by = ""
    var applicants = List<ApplicantsEntity>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class ApplicantsEntity: Object {
    dynamic var applicant_id = 0
    dynamic var applicantable_type = ""
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var first_name = ""
    dynamic var last_name = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var firm_id = 0
    dynamic var company_id = 0
    dynamic var has_portal_access = Bool()
    dynamic var mobile_number = ""
    dynamic var phone_number = ""
    dynamic var fax = ""
    dynamic var website = ""
    dynamic var street_address = ""
    dynamic var locality = ""
    dynamic var city = ""
    dynamic var state = ""
    dynamic var postal_code = ""
    dynamic var landmark = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Then you can add an extension to create objects directly from the output of `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:, options:)`:

```
import RealmSwift

extension CaseAreaEntity {
    class func create(from jsonResponse: [String: Any]) throws {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            if let jsonCc = jsonResponse["cc"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                try realm.write {
                    for json in jsonCc {
                        realm.create(CaseAreaEntity.self, value: json, update: true)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch { throw error }
    }
}
```

With the classes and extension above, you can simply do this:

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] { 
       try CaseAreaEntity.create(from: jsonResult)
}
```

Where `jsonResult` is the json output you show in the first code paragraph in your question.

```
  [1]: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json
```

Comment: sorry still i'm having problem with storing data's. I'm not able to store applicants values it return like `applicants = RLMArray 0x6080000fdd00> ( );`

Comment: If you try what I suggest after *EDIT:* you will get applicants as `List<ApplicantsEntity>`. I would recommend using this object directly but you can transform it to a "normal" Swift Array by casting `Array(applicants)`